# OSX per app network throughput via nettop

Tags: macos, cocoa, networking

The OSX command line tool nettop (I think it was added with Lion) can display per app network throughput without requiring root privileges. I browsed through the Darwin source code on http://www.opensource.apple.com/ but couldn't find it's source code. Is it open source at all or did I just missed it. Incase the source is not publicly available, does anyone have an idea via which api nettop is getting its data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nettop` is open source only in its BSD version, but Apple's version uses their private `NetworkStatistics` framework (new in Lion) so I doubt you will find the sources since Apple tends to not release private code.